# Vue router complaining about route guard if navigation is done programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Working with Vue `2.7`, and Vue Router `3.0.0` (currently updating from router `2.x.x`, it's a pretty old codebase).

I have a generic sidebar nav component that handles navigation in several places across the application. Nothing fancy, it's just a list of items, each of them taking you to a different route.

Now, for some reason these components all do programmatic navigation via `$router.push()`, rather than doing it via a `router-link`. Something like this:

```js
<ListItem v-for="item in list" @click="navigateTo(item.url)">

<script>
// As a method
navigateTo(url) {
  this.$router.push(url);
}
</script>
```

Note that the method is verbatim what's in the codebase, it's not doing anything special or fancy here.

This works fine for the most part, but I do get Vue throwing errors in the console when navigating to/from components that have navigation guards like `beforeRouteUpdate`, specifically if the middleware calls the `next()` method. It specifically complains about Navigation being cancelled, and I'm not really sure why.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "routeA" to "routeB" with a new navigation.
```

The above happens every single time `$router.push` gets called and the page that the app leads to is one that has a route guard, for example one of the affected components has this guard:

```js
async beforeRouteUpdate(to, _from, next) {
  await this.$store.dispatch('integrations/filterIntegrations', to.params.filter).then(() => {
    this.searchIntegrations();
  });

  next();
}
```

It's a route that gets the contents of the page based on the `filter` param, so I simply call a VueX action that fetches the appropriate items, [as is recommended by the Vue Router docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) to do when dealing with re-used routes

If I just refactor the component a bit and wrap the list item in a `router-link`, I get no complaints whatsoever and everything works as it did, but it does involve some style-related reworks that I'd rather avoid in this particular junction.

Am I missing something in why it's complaining in this situation? I'm not actually interrupting any navigation here, I'm simply fetching some data then letting it proceed to the next route immediately, and there's also no double `next()` which is a common pitfall here. What exactly is wrong with my `beforeRouteUpdate` guard?